# libgdx sprite-sheet based animation scaling

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, screen

I am quite new to libgdx and android programming in general. I am having problems rendering a sprite-sheet-based animation, and getting it to be the same size on different screen sizes.

If I run the following code on my note 4, the animation is quite small, on the Zenfone 2 instead it's quite big, and lastly on my laptop it is jut so small it can barely be seen.

I really don't understand why this happens, and how to make it the same on the two phones. I thought that using an orthographic camera with ingame units and a viewport would do the job, but I might be doing something wrong because it doesn't.

I am following the book "libgdx cross-platform game development cookbook".

I would hugely appreciate any help on how to properly use in game units to get the game to be the same on different screen sizes, so that a 512x512 px image isn't tiny on the note4 and huge on the Zenfone (each frame of my animation is 512px squared).

And as far as the pc goes, I just have no clue what is going on, I would really appreciate any explanation on why that happens!

Thank you all!

```
package com.mygdxGame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.PlayMode;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private static final float WORLD_TO_SCREEN = 1.0f / 100.0f;
    private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 12.80f;
    private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT = 7.20f;
    private static final float FRAME_DURATION = 1.0f / 20.0f;
    private TextureAtlas techmanAtlas;
    private Animation techmanRun;
    private float animationTime;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Viewport viewport;
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    @Override
    public void create(){
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),        Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        animationTime = 0.0f;
        techmanAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("TechMan.atlas"));
        Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> techmanRegions = new Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion>(techmanAtlas.getRegions());
        techmanRegions.sort(new RegionComparator());
        techmanRun = new Animation(FRAME_DURATION, techmanRegions, PlayMode.LOOP);
        camera.position.set(SCENE_WIDTH * 0.5f, SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.5f, 0.0f);

}

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        batch.dispose();
        techmanAtlas.dispose();
}

    @Override
    public void render(){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        animationTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        TextureRegion techmanFrame = techmanRun.getKeyFrame(animationTime);
        int width = techmanFrame.getRegionWidth();
        int height = techmanFrame.getRegionWidth();
        float originX = width * 0.5f;
        float originY = height * 0.5f;

        batch.draw(techmanFrame,
                1.0f - originX, 3.70f - originY,
                originX, originY,
                width, height, //width, height
                WORLD_TO_SCREEN, WORLD_TO_SCREEN,
                0.0f);
        batch.draw(techmanRun.getKeyFrame(animationTime), 100.0f, 275.0f);
        batch.end();
}
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height){
        viewport.update(width, height, false);
}

    private static class RegionComparator implements Comparator<AtlasRegion>     {
        @Override
        public int compare(AtlasRegion region1, AtlasRegion region2){
            return region1.name.compareTo(region2.name);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the proper way to use viewport:

```
 viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
```

You should initialize viewport with constant values, 800x600, for example, and use them when writing code:

```
 viewport = new FitViewport(WORLD_WIDTH,WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
```

The image will be streched/resized automaticly when rendering, you dont need to do that:

```
batch.draw(techman.Frame,x,y,width,height);
```

PS: Do not call `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);` inside the render() method. You only need to do that once.

Documentation:

- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports
- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

Comment: Thank you! Would passing "SCENE_WIDTH" and "SCENE_HEIGHT" in the viewport work then? And in batch.draw should the first parameter be "techman.Frame" then just width height x y?

Comment: @EdoardoPona yes, it would work. You should choose the world coordinates that make thing easy to calculate in your world (I reccomend the same resolution you make concept art in). And yes, i fixed the mistake in the draw method, thanks

Comment: yes! it worked! I had to add one last thing though, in the Gdx.gl.clclear method :  " | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT", Thanks!